# limitation of unions of sets

Tags: limits, measure-theory

$\mathbb N$ is the positive integer, for $A\subset \mathbb N$, define 
$$p(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\#\{j\in A:1\le j\le n\}$$
if the limit exists. $\#$ is the number of elements of the set .$\mathcal C$ is the family of the subsets of $\mathbb N$ which the limit exists. I am asked to show whether $(\mathbb N,\mathcal C, p)$ is a measurable space. The answer is no since $p$ does not satisfy the countable additivity by choosing $A_k=\{k\}$, but my question is whether $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

I can't show the close in union either, if $p(A),p(B)$ exists, does $p(A\cup B)$ exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the even integers.  Let 
$B = \{n: n \equiv \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor \mod 2\}$.  Then $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal C$, but $A \cup B$ is not.

Comment: do you mean $n-\lfloor log_2(n)\rfloor = 2k$?, but I find it abstract and I don't know why $B\in\mathcal C$

Comment: $B$ consists of the odd numbers from $2$ to $3$, the even numbers from $4$ to $7$, the odd numbers from $8$ to $15$, etc.  $\#\{j \in B : 1 \le j \le n\}$ differs from  $\#\{j \in A : 1 \le j \le n\}$ by at most $1$.